# nested_form gem rails 4 shows two nested form(fields)on click link_to_add

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On click "Add an Item",add  two 'fields_for :item' nested form(fields)

Need help :)))

Assosiation:

Menu(has_many :items),
Items(belongs_to :menu)

```
<%= nested_form_for(@menu) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Title" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Description" %>
  </div>

  <h3>Items</h3>
   <%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :name %><br>     
     <%= i.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Name" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :price %><br>
     <%= i.text_field :price, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Price" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :description %><br>
     <%= i.text_area :description, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Description" %>
    </div>

    <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove this item", :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an Item", :items, :class=>"btn btn-default" %></p>

  <%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, :value => params[:restauranti_id]`enter code here`

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Create Menu', :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Add this twice:

```
<%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :name %><br>     
     <%= i.text_field :name, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Name" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :price %><br>
     <%= i.text_field :price, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Price" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <%= i.label :description %><br>
     <%= i.text_area :description, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder => "Description" %>
    </div>

    <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove this item", :class=>"btn btn-default" %>
    <% end %>
```

My current version is 'rails', '4.1.6'...
Help me:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form" %> in your layout (:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Mi solution was the next:

In the file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` i had the next code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>RoR 1</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then i removed this code

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>
```

And i solved the problem.